# import sqlite3 with a where var like statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have this code :

```
Title= "somewords"
itemID = somenumbers
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('C:\\db.sqlite')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT itemID FROM itemAttachments WHERE path LIKE "%?%"  ', (Title, ))
cursor.execute('SELECT key FROM items WHERE itemID =? ', (itemID,))
```

The second statement with the `where item=?` works but the first one with the `like` gives me troubles.

I have tried many combinaisons like `"+Title+"` and `{} .format(Title)`, adding or removing the "`%...%"` but each time I am getting an error: either `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied` or `sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `%` to the parameter:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT itemID FROM itemAttachments WHERE path LIKE ?', ('%{}%'.format(Title), ))
```